# set jxbrowser as default browser instead of IE/Firefox/Chrome

Tags: jxbrowser

How can I set my jxbrowser as default browser. Lets suppose I have run java program which open jxbrowser.
Now I want to set that as default browser. Can anybody suggest is that possible ?

Comment: yes for sure... you change it under regedit manually 
https://superuser.com/questions/445612/how-to-find-default-browser-in-registry-windows-7

Comment: Thank you, lets suppose my java application is java TestJXBrowser, in this case can you please help how to provide that ? or we need to convert my java application to any jar / any executable like bat file ? I will try these approaches. Thank you so much once again.